# What is HiDPI ? and why is a seperate media query and sprite needed for such devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I was just going through the source of icheck.js and in the css I found the following rules defined:

```
/* HiDPI support */
@media (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi), (min-resolution: 1.25dppx) {
    .icheckbox_flat-green,
    .iradio_flat-green {
        background-image: url(green@2x.png);
        -webkit-background-size: 176px 22px;
        background-size: 176px 22px;
    }
}
```

For normal devices the sprit created is below:

[image]

And for devices for the media query above the sprit created is the below one:

[image]

Which is ofcourse quite big in size , can somebody explain what is the use of this media query and why is this extra sprite needed ?

The plugin I am talking about is of course **[THIS](http://icheck.fronteed.com/)** one.

So why the separate media query and sprite ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screens with a high DPI (such as those marketed as Apple Retina Displays) pack more pixels into the same amount of physical space which allows for sharper text and images.

In order to take advantage of them, you need to supply images which have more pixels in them to start with.

Comment: thank you sir , nice theoretical answer , but could you give an example ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik — I did. Apple Retina Displays.

Answer (score 1):

HDPI is used for targeting High Screen Resolution Devices to render without any distortion.

[Reference Link](http://engineering.hoteltonight.com/using-media-queries-for-multi-platform)

Hope this helps!